# Keep newest value by duplicate dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called 'staff':

```
Account   Score   UpdateTime                UpdateTime_order               
K1897     A       2023-09-08 14:57:58.113   1
K1897     B       2023-09-08 14:57:57.896   2
K1897     B       2023-08-01 10:07:57.487   3
K1897     B       2023-06-28 07:23:57.696   4
K1897     B       2023-06-05 14:20:13.789   5
K1898     C       2023-06-04 14:20:13.789   1
```

Every staff can only have one score per day, so Account K1897's score should be A at 2023-09-08. (The score changed from B to A that day)

To solve this problem, I decided to convert datetime to date format, then kept the newest UpdateTime when they are duplicate.

For example, I deselected the row when UpdateTime_order=2 from Account K1897 because its original UpdateTime 2023-09-08 14:57:57.896 < 2023-09-08 14:57:58.113

```
Account   Score   UpdateTime   UpdateTime_order               
K1897     A       2023-09-08   1      
K1897     B       2023-08-01   3
K1897     B       2023-06-28   4
K1897     B       2023-06-05   5
K1898     C       2023-06-04   1
```

Then reordered the UpdateTime_order based on new result.

What I expected:

```
Account   Score   UpdateTime   UpdateTime_order             
K1897     A       2023-09-08   1
K1897     B       2023-08-01   2
K1897     B       2023-06-28   3
K1897     B       2023-06-05   4
K1898     C       2023-06-04   1
```

My code:

```
;WITH CTE_staff AS (
select 
Account, 
Score, 
CAST([UpdateTime] AS Date) UpdateDate,
UpdateTime, 
UpdateTime_order
FROM staff
)
select 
Account, 
Score, 
UpdateDate,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC) as UpdateTime_order3
from(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Account, UpdateDate ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC) as UpdateTime_order2 
from CTE_staff
) jj
where jj.UpdateTime_order2=1
```

It ran succesfully, but I think I wrote it in a complicated way by creating new columns. Wandering if there's an easy way to do this?

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/dJ1qw3Lt

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: *"I am using SQL [Server] 2018."* Unlikely, it doesn't exist. There were releases in 2017 and  2019, but not in 2018.

Comment: @ThomA sorry, that was a typo! mine is 2008 version

Comment: Oof; SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support way back in **2019**; you really should be getting that instance upgraded. Using such an old, and insecure, version of SQL Server is a vulnerability for both you, and your clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to accomplish it using one `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the most recently updated row per account and day :

```
SELECT Account, Score, UpdateTime, UpdateTime_order
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account, CAST(UpdateTime AS Date) ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC) AS RN
  FROM staff
) AS S
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC
```

---

It is also possible to use `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function `MAX()`:
We need first determine the maximum update time per account and day:

```
SELECT Account, MAX(UpdateTime) AS MAX_UpdateTime
FROM staff
GROUP BY Account, CAST(UpdateTime AS DATE)
```

Then Join this dataset with the table as follow :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM staff s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Account, MAX(UpdateTime) AS MAX_UpdateTime
  FROM staff
  GROUP BY Account, CAST(UpdateTime AS DATE)
) AS t ON S.Account = t.Account AND s.UpdateTime = t.MAX_UpdateTime
ORDER BY s.UpdateTime DESC
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dDkABtFh)

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/_NZfe5JW

```sql
WITH RankedStaff AS (
    SELECT
        Account,
        Score,
        UpdateTime,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account, CONVERT(DATE, UpdateTime) ORDER BY UpdateTime DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        staff
)
SELECT
    Account,
    Score,
    UpdateTime
FROM
    RankedStaff
WHERE
    RowNum = 1;
```

This query uses a common table expression (CTE) named `RankedStaff` to assign a row number to each row within a partition defined by the combination of `Account` and the date part of `UpdateTime`. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function is used to order the rows within each partition based on `UpdateTime` in descending order, so the row with the newest `UpdateTime` gets the row number 1.

The final `SELECT` statement then filters the results to only include rows where `RowNum` is equal to 1, meaning it's the row with the newest `UpdateTime` for each day for each account.

This should give you a result where only the rows with the latest `UpdateTime` for each day for each account are included.

Answer (score 1):

This should return result you said you expect:

```
with cte_staff as
  (select Account, Score, CAST([UpdateTime] AS Date) UpdateDate, UpdateTime_order,
      row_number() over (partition by Account, cast([UpdateTime] as Date) order by updateTime desc) rn
   from staff
  )
select Account, Score, UpdateDate, 
  row_number() over (partition by Account order by Score, rn) UpdateTime_order
from cte_staff
where rn = 1
order by Account, UpdateTime_order; 


Account     Score   UpdateDate  UpdateTime_order
K1897       A       2023-09-08  1
K1897       B       2023-06-05  2
K1897       B       2023-06-28  3
K1897       B       2023-08-01  4
K1898       C       2023-06-04  1
```

See the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z-3tLu72).